# Pandas DataFrame.empty() gives TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My DataFrame pipeline needs to handle empty and malformed results, and I added a test `df.empty()` and encountered this error:

```
(Pdb) isinstance(tabledf, pd.DataFrame)
True
(Pdb) tabledf.empty()
*** TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
(Pdb) tabledf
  From Location  Account Description  Value        TableName
0  NaN      NaN         nan       TOTAL       0  countreport
(Pdb) tabledf.shape
(1, 6)
```

Clearly this example DF would return `False`, because it's not empty (I'll just test for only one row) but now I'm curious why I'm getting this error its not a `bool`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.empty` is not a callable method, but a property.

Just use it as `tabledf.empty` rather than `tabledf.empty()`

The error you are getting is due to the fact that what you are doing is akin to:

```
>>> some_boolean = True
>>> some_boolean()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-02ece9c024ce> in <module>
      1 boolean = False
----> 2 boolean()

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: Doah! That should be the error, "I'm not a method, dude."

Answer (score 3):

`empty` is an attriibute, not a method, s remove the `()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
print(df.empty)
# True

df=pd.DataFrame({"a": [1]})
print(df.empty)
# False
```